# How do you force reload of modules in Celery

Tags: celery

For some reason, --autoreload doesn't work even though pyinotify is installed.

Is there a way to tell all workers to restart and load the new version of the modules?

I tried:

```
celery multi restart \*
```

But all it does is create a bunch of process with no task modules loaded.

Comment: Do you try this in development or production environment?

Comment: dev. I just installed celery and started toying with it, modifying the sample tasks.add function.